# Firestore read and write cost optimization

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on this social media site that feeds users, user generated content(only text0) and to minimize the reads, I planned to store 500 jsons(only text ~ 300kb) in a single document and whenever some ones initially ones the app I send the document containing that days posts, and store it in the local cache using ISAR but the problem is we can have only 1 write per sec per document in firestore and thus if many users start to add new content then firestore deny.

1. How can i overcome this issue?
2. Is there any better way to deal with this situation by minimizing cost and maximizing efficiency?
3. Should i use firebase firestore bundel feature to further reduce reads as the app is 70% reads and 30% create and delete and 0 updates?

Is there any other way to deal with this and optimise further?

I was thinking that if 1 create seperate 6-7 collections and various documents in them for people to write, and when they are denied they get it on other document and manually merge them at the end of the day in the same 1 document with 500 json format.

Answer (score 0):

Some drawbacks with this approach:

- it will increase bandwidth usage: you will retrieve the content of 500 docs for a user that may only read 5 of them.
- you cannot easily write security rules for this structure (if possible at all)
- you wont be able to selectively query documents, like all posts from a given author sorted by creation dates
- as you mention, concurrent writes are not possible except with a complex solution that may require additional writes
- not to forget that you have to handle the edge case when the doc's size goes over 1Mo, splitting it in 2 or creating a new one
  ...

My advice: use one document for each user's post, this is how Firestore is meant to be used. Then when your app grows and you see that writes are an issue you can optimize, you will then have a better understanding about how it is used and the best trade-offs for your cases

Comment: Hey! Thnaks for the reply, I wanted to ask if there are anyother solutions to this, as creating seperate doc for every post will endup in a lot of reads,

Comment: @Newbiedevflutter Firestore is designed for this. You can optimize a bit by only loading posts that have changed this the last time you laoded them